# how can openlayers have mobile.css file as style

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile

I try to make openlayers work in mobile devices, so it can go fullscreen.

I cannot just put `width` and `height` to be 100%.

Here is why

```
<div id="content"> //contains map, forms, images etc
    <div id="mapcont" >//contains just map's div
         <div id='map_element'></div>//map
    </div>
</div>    


//the css
.content{
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    position: static;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    width: 50%;
}

#map_element{
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
z-index:1; 
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
}

#mapcont{
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
z-index:1; 
text-align:center;
position:relative;
padding-bottom:60%;
padding-left:0.1%;
padding-right:0.1%;
}
```

To have a responsive map , its container must have a height. `content` div cannot have height, because it will not be responsive. This is why I put `mapcont`.  Map is responsive , but in mobiles is very small (see image) and cannot go fullscreen, because the `width` and `height` are *already* 100%.

So I was wondering how can I use the `style.mobile.css` as a default css style?

This CSS file is placed in `theme/default`.

I try to load the CSS like so

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../theme/default/style.mobile.css" type="text/css">`

but I see no change on my site.

I found tutorials on how to overwrite the default styles, or how to create new themes. But nothing on how to use the already existing CSS.

[image]

***EDIT***

My apologies if this is still unclear. I was asking for details , so I can implement the rest of the code by my self. Maybe I should show what I am generally trying to do. The whole idea.

This maybe help you understand better. Keep in mind what I said about mobiles, fullscreen and divs and check the following.

User on *pc* clicks "the map" in the menu and goes here (map, images, forms in the same page)

[image]

User on *mobile* clicks "the map" in the menu and goes here (just the map, fullscreen)

[image]

If user wants to see the images and forms clicks "back button" (right corner) and goes here
(just images forms, no map)

[image]

If he wants to see the map again, clicks the "back to the map button"

Thanks again for your time, your answers and your patience

Comment: have a look at [this](http://maps.roadguide.ph) on a Tablet. It runs quite nicely on tabs, Pc's (Not phones, yet) I just used absolute positioning and then pick up the   window.addEventListener("orientationchange", checkOrientation, false); to handle all the css to redisplay windows on Browser Re-sizes, tablet orientation changes, etc. Is this what you want? Map responsiveness has nothing to do with the container positioning, you may like ot clarify what you mean by that in your question.

Comment: @Mark C All I say is that `width` and `height` of the `divs` are *already* 100%. So I can not set it 100% to have fullscreen, as the openlayers examples says. And I cannot load the mobile css. I do what openayer says and I see no change in my site. And I cannot edit the code I have now, because map is responsive now. So I have no solution...Drives me crazy!!

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific with your question and what you are asking. Editing your question with some code may help. The code you posted does not show hat its 100% only your comments. How do you know they are 100%? Where is the code/css that sets that. A Screen shot of what you actually get may also be helpful!!!

Comment: @MarkC Hello. I just edit the question. Thanks again

Comment: Does the CSS in this example work for you: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fullScreen.html? It has always worked for me, on all devices I have tested. Further more, how are you making the map responsive?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Thanks. I have seen that. Does not work for me, because it has map inside body. I have map inside mapcont, inside content div, inside body. Right now my code is responsive because map and mapcont have percentages for width/height, so can adopt their size, as you can see in the image. To re-frase my problem, map and mapcont cannot go fullscreen because are "trapped" inside content div

Comment: You need to understand the CSS box model . Why can't you make the content div 100%?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe This will party solve it, because the map will apear bigger. But not full screen. Content div contains other stuff too, like forms, images etc. Not just the map.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I just edited again, hope is more clear now.

Comment: @slevin: So where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Map cannot go fullscreen, because is "trapped" inside `content` and `width,height` are alerady 100%. The only thing I can do is expand `content` width, so map will also expand its width. But will not go fullscreen and cover the page (cover content, header, footer etc)

Comment: So are you trying to style your map differently for pc and mobile? If so, please edit your question to state that. If you want the map div outside your content div, you can use jquery to move the div, or write different css and divs for mobile and pc pages and point your users to the appropriate pages. Thats why you often see a http://m.sitename.com. Thats how they do it. Downside, you have to maintain two sites, butbthis is not difficult if you use server side includes for a lot of the common code. ..

Answer (score 1):

You have your content  width set at 50%, then your map-content nested inside you content div set to 100%, therefore, the map-content will always be 100% of the parent div, which is 50% of its parent container. You should also use absolute positioned elements and you need to specify top and left positions.

You don't need map-element.

This will give you a 100% sized content div on the page, with the map filling the content div with 10px margin between the map and content:

```
<div id="content"> //contains map, forms, images etc
    <div id="mapcont" >//Put you map here

    </div>
</div>    


//the css
.content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

#mapcont{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    z-index:1; 
    position:absolute;
    top:1;
    left:1;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
   }
```